# Почему стили не применяются к второму элементу?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Всем привет
Есть подобная структура :

```
<tr>
  <td class="UpCalThIndex"></td>
  <td class="UpCalTh"></td>
  <td class="UpCalThIndex test"></td>
</tr>
```

И такой скрипт :

```
var leftOffset = 0;
var rightOffset = 0;

$('#calendar-container').scroll(function() {
    $('.UpCalThIndex').not('.test').css({
    'position' : 'absolute',
    'left' : $(this).scrollLeft() + leftOffset,
    'z-index': 9999,
    'display': 'block',
    'height': '50px'
  });
  $('.UpCalThIndex.test').css({
    'position' : 'absolute',
    'left': 'auto',
    'right' : $(this).scrollRight() + rightOffset,
    'z-index': 9999,
    'display': 'block',
    'height': '50px'
  });

});
```

В результате, отрабатываются стили только для элемента `$('.UpCalThIndex').not('.test')`, а для второго нет. Почему???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кое-где кое-что пришлось заменить, все работает (надо логи смотреть где и что у тебя не так) ... Думается проблема в scrollRight() - без понятия что это.

```js
var leftOffset = 0;
var rightOffset = 0;

$('.UpCalThIndex').not('.test').css({
  'position' : 'absolute',
  'left' : 200,
  'z-index': 9999,
  'display': 'block',
  'height': '50px'
});
$('.UpCalThIndex.test').css({
  'position' : 'absolute',
  'left': 'auto',
  'right' : 200,
  'z-index': 9999,
  'display': 'block',
  'height': '50px'
});

console.log($('.UpCalThIndex').not('.test').attr('style'));
console.log($('.UpCalThIndex.test').attr('style'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="UpCalThIndex"></td>
    <td class="UpCalTh"></td>
    <td class="UpCalThIndex test"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```